# Is it possible to stream audio or video file with https url in media element control using wpf application?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, mediaelement

While play media (using `Play()` method) with https url getting exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Is there any alternate way to make it working?

I have written below code:

```
MeMediaElement.Source = new Uri(txtPath.Text, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
MeMediaElement.Play();
```

Comment: What is the inner exception? Any other details?

Comment: Inner Exception is "null"

Comment: Stack Trace:    at System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayerState.OpenMedia(Uri source)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayerState.SetSource(Uri source)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayerState.Open(Uri source)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer.Open(Uri source)
   at System.Windows.Controls.AVElementHelper.HandleStateChange()
   at System.Windows.Controls.AVElementHelper.SetState(MediaState mediaState)
   at System.Windows.Controls.MediaElement.Play()

Comment: It seems there is a problem with the path of your media element.

Comment: Yes. but same url is working in windows media player and web browser.

Comment: i have found one post for same problem: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/934355/in-a-wpf-standalone-application-exe-when-the-source-of-a-mediaelement-is-set-to-a-https-uri-it-throws-a-nullreferenceexception please check if you able to help me.

Comment: I'm afraid there is not an easy solution for that. What about downloading file to local disk and then streaming?

Comment: No. that will be not good way when file size is very large like More then 10MB.